# Unable to align having 3 elements in a row. One should be to the left, and the rest should be centered

Tags: html, css

I have the follwing:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.el1 {
  margin-right: 10vw;
}

.el2 {}

.el3 {}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <Button class="el1">Info</Button>
  <input class="el2"></input>
  <Button class="el3">Search</Button>
</div>
```

The problem is, that this created two `centered elements` and the first `element` having an unknown `position` since it depends on the `screen size`.

Instead, I want it to be next to the beginning of the `screen` on the `left` side, `left aligned` with the other two `elements` sitting in the `center of the screen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap `input` and last `button` in a `div` container and set the position to absolute.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.child-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
}

.el1 {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.el2 {}

.el3 {}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <Button class="el1">Info</Button>
  <div class="child-wrapper">
    <input class="el2"></input>
    <Button class="el3">Search</Button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `.el1` `position: absolute`, and set the `align-items` of the container to `center`. The HTML structure remains as is.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.el1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <Button class="el1">Info</Button>
  <input class="el2" />
  <Button class="el3">Search</Button>
</div>
```